# Could someone recommend me a plain js/jquery clickable calendar widget that works with bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calendar, bootstrap-5

I am looking a for a plain clickable calendar widget to display on my site. I'm using html/css/bootstrap 5/jquery 3.6
I want the calendar days to be clickable as I'll show different content on another div based on different dates.  My main goal is to ultimately show time slots available for booking a movie based on click for each day in the calendar.
I also want the calendar to have prev next buttons for different months.

But unfortunately till now I couldn't find one widget/library that is nice and working. Half don't work with bootstrap 5.
Could anyone recommend me a good calendar? A calendar widget not a datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try fullcalender.

Reference :- https://fullcalendar.io/